# Using Select within a select to use 2 calculated column Oracle Sql

Tags: sql, oracle

so I have a to make a query that will fetch some dates from a table, do some operations to determine the newest one, then determine if I have to check for 7 or 15 years in the past, then have a yes/no row to tell me what to do.  The problem is I can't quite get how to do it.  I looked around and it seems I may need to use a SELECT within a SELECT but can't seem to figure it out.  I guess my syntax isn't on point or something, table or view does not exist is what I have for now.

```
SELECT fact.NO_CONTRAT_OFFICIEL AS noContrat,
Case When to_date(fact.VSTDTCHG, 'yyyymmdd') < to_date(fact.VSTDICHK, 'yyyymmdd') And to_date(fact.VSTDTCHG, 'yyyymmdd') < to_date(fact.VSTDIFIN, 'yyyymmdd') Then to_date(fact.VSTDTCHG, 'yyyymmdd')
        When to_date(fact.VSTDICHK, 'yyyymmdd') < to_date(fact.VSTDTCHG, 'yyyymmdd') And to_date(fact.VSTDICHK, 'yyyymmdd') < to_date(fact.VSTDIFIN, 'yyyymmdd') Then to_date(fact.VSTDICHK, 'yyyymmdd')
        Else to_date(fact.VSTDIFIN, 'yyyymmdd')
        End As TheMin,
Case When fact.NO_CONTRAT_OFFICIEL = virage.NO_CONTR Then sysdate - 15*365.25
        Else sysdate - 7*365.25
        End As Operation,
(SELECT NO_CONTRAT_OFFICIEL, Operation, TheMin,
    Case When TheMin < Operation Then 'yes'
    Else 'no'
    End As yesno 
    From XC4DSAV facts) as yesnotable
FROM XC4DSAV fact
JOIN yesnotable T1
    ON fact.NO_CONTRAT_OFFICIEL = T1.NO_CONTRAT_OFFICIEL
FULL OUTER JOIN STAR.EVENEMENT star
    ON fact.NO_CONTRAT_OFFICIEL = star.NO_CONTRAT_DIFFUSE
JOIN VIRAGE.CONTRAT virage
    ON fact.VSTNOCNT_VIRAGE = virage.NO_CONTR
WHERE fact.NO_CONTRAT_OFFICIEL IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to interpret the somewhat larger query.  Here, I've used that as a view within the from clause, then just select from it the columns and calculations you want.

```
SELECT noContrat, Operation, TheMin,
    Case When TheMin < Operation Then 'yes'
    Else 'no'
    End As yesno 
from (SELECT fact.NO_CONTRAT_OFFICIEL AS noContrat,
      Case When to_date(fact.VSTDTCHG, 'yyyymmdd') < to_date(fact.VSTDICHK, 'yyyymmdd') And to_date(fact.VSTDTCHG, 'yyyymmdd') < to_date(fact.VSTDIFIN, 'yyyymmdd') Then to_date(fact.VSTDTCHG, 'yyyymmdd')
              When to_date(fact.VSTDICHK, 'yyyymmdd') < to_date(fact.VSTDTCHG, 'yyyymmdd') And to_date(fact.VSTDICHK, 'yyyymmdd') < to_date(fact.VSTDIFIN, 'yyyymmdd') Then to_date(fact.VSTDICHK, 'yyyymmdd')
              Else to_date(fact.VSTDIFIN, 'yyyymmdd')
              End As TheMin,
      Case When fact.NO_CONTRAT_OFFICIEL = virage.NO_CONTR Then sysdate - 15*365.25
              Else sysdate - 7*365.25
              End As Operation
      FROM XC4DSAV fact
      FULL OUTER JOIN STAR.EVENEMENT star
          ON fact.NO_CONTRAT_OFFICIEL = star.NO_CONTRAT_DIFFUSE
      JOIN VIRAGE.CONTRAT virage
          ON fact.VSTNOCNT_VIRAGE = virage.NO_CONTR
      WHERE fact.NO_CONTRAT_OFFICIEL IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch @unleached that is indeed correct and it helped me a lot. Cheers